# You know you have been LEGOing too long when

Tags: afol, popular-culture

Inspired by [this webpage on raytracing](http://runevision.com/misc/jokes/) I was trying to find out whether something similar exists for LEGOing (playing with LEGO). However, I couldn't find any references to jokes like "You know you have been LEGOing too long when you are getting excited about the difference between bright light orange and yellow".

Are you aware of any jokes about playing with LEGO, possibly by people who think that LEGO is for kids only?

Comment: ...you have "Lepin" written in the center of your dart board.

Comment: ...you smile when you hear the name [Travis](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9729/what-is-the-travis-brick)

Comment: ...you know the conversion factor from km/h to studs per second.

Comment: ...you are worried about LEGOing too long.

Comment: ...you build a LEGO model of your house with a LEGO model of your house inside a LEGO model of your house ... aarrghhh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know you have been LEGOing too long when

### you have permanent stud prints on your fingers

[image]

([That's technically a tattoo pictured](http://techland.time.com/2010/07/12/brick-artist-nathan-sawayas-new-lego-themed-ink/), but you get the idea)

Comment: Is that a real tattoo?

Comment: @Aziraphale Yep, that's LEGO Certified Professional Nathan Sawaya's thumb.

Comment: "Thumbs up" for you answer! My plan was to have a brainstorming of this type of LEGO jokes. That is backfiring a bit, I don't really know why.

Answer (score 6):

I know i have when my kids get tired of waiting for me in the Lego store & leave me to go to Starbucks

Comment: haha, liked that one. hope they get decaf

Answer (score 5):

When you've been waiting almost 40 years for your favorite colors to become real.  The Lego Movie 2 colors (teal and aqua!!!) and the teal brick separator are like a dream come true.

Comment: Nice one! Welcome to Bricks.SE

Answer (score 3):

When you're correcting anyone and everyone that says "Legos" regardless of their age.
When you're editing every question and answer I post to correct Lego to LEGO. :P
When your Lego collection is worth more than your car and/or house.
When you have an entire room in your house dedicated to Lego.
When you want to show every child and parent at the PAB wall how to get the most in their cup, but usually manage to keep your mouth shut.
When you spend more time sorting pieces than building with them.
When the "book" collection is your house is 90% Lego manuals.
When your Lego collection is larger than your kids collection.
When you buy multiples of sets "just for the parts".
When it's mandatory to walk down the Lego isle in any store that has one.
When you can't complain about your wife's shoe collection because it pales in comparison to your Lego collection.
When you have developed a legitimate hatred of stickers in Lego sets. Either because it seems "cheap" or, no matter how perfectly you apply them, some will wither and die with age.
When you've rolled up to the check-out with a shopping cart overflowing with storage drawers and/or containers.
When your fingertips are numb from pulling 1000's of Lego pieces apart, but it doesn't stop you.
Ok, I should stop now...

Comment: :) Guilty as charged with #2, but if you care: https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/do-we-agree-on-how-to-capitalize-lego?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I am sure you are talking about your kids' collection and not about your kids collection :)

Comment: @Aziraphale -  That took me a sec.  Yes, my collection of children isn't nearly as large as my collection of Lego.  LOL, that's an important apostrophe!  That's too funny, I'm leaving it :)

Answer (score 2):

...when you´re a dedicated AFOL and cannot laugh about Lego jokes

Comment: This has a deep truth, indeed.