# What does the acronym SPUA stand for?

Tags: terminology

I once heard someone use the acronym SPUA while referring to a LEGO piece. What does that stand for and what does it mean?

Comment: Stackable Parts Utility Application, Series Premiere Under Association, Space Pirates Universe Aces, Small Pieces Utilization Accessory

Comment: @RobertColumbia You seem to be suffering from [some severe case of overLEGOing](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/you-know-you-have-been-legoing-too-long-when)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SPUA - Special Part Used Again, a part which is seemingly only for a particular set or theme, but is used again

[List of LEGO Abbreviations](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_LEGO_Abbreviations) from [Brickipeda](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Wiki)